# VueJS not open home page with "/" route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

I want to show a simple home page with a `h1` text, but it doesn't work. I configured route and added it to `main.js`. When I browse to `localhost:8080` nothing is showing. I can't see the reason to it not works.

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'home'
    }
</script>
```

**/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Home',
            component: Home
        }
    ]
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>client</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but client doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you get any error in the console? Do you have an element with id = "app" in your `ìndex.html` ?

Comment: On console have a warning: `[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.`. On the `index.html` I've a element called by id `app`

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're using the wrong Vue library (runtime-only), but you need the full version. did you setup the webpack config yourself or are you using vue cli?

Comment: I've created simple project wit `vue create client`. Just vue cli. I should have used `vue init webpack client`  ?

Comment: No, `vue create` is the newer, preferred variant to init a vue project. I think i found the problem, i'll quickly write up an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@vue/cli` per default only uses the vue runtime, but not the [vue compiler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only) ( the compiler is needed if you want to use inline template strings)

To work around this you can either [turn on the runtimeCompiler](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) in your `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  "runtimeCompiler": true
};
```

Or change your code to use the `render()` function instead:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

to

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app")
```

Btw if you're using `@vue/cli`, you can choose the `Manually select features` during `vue create`.
When you select `Router` as a feature you will get an project bootstrapped with `vue-router` that will work out of the box.

Comment: My app not have the `vue.config.js` file, but option 2 fixed my problem.

Comment: @Augusto `@vue/cli` will not automatically generate it for you, you need to manually create the `vue.config.js` file.